# Create typolink with parameters and custom name within COA

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typolink

I want to create a typolink from the current page but with other name and some additional GET parameter. E.g.

```
<a href="mytypo3site.com/this-is-the-current-side.html?someParam=1" title="My custom title">My custom name</a>
```

This is my code which only prints out a text with MyCustomName.

```
lib.tsfooter >
lib.tsfooter = COA
lib.tsfooter {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value (
   <!-- some HTML code-->
  )

  20 = TEXT
  20.value = MyCustomName
  20.stdWrap.typolink {
    data = TSFE:id
    addQueryString = 1
    addQueryString.method = get
    additionalParams = &myCustomParameter=1
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove the ``stdWrap``from ``20.stdWrap.typolink``. ``TEXT`` already has ``stdWrap`` on top level. Otherwise this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lib.tsfooter >
lib.tsfooter = COA
lib.tsfooter {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value (
   <!-- some HTML code-->
  )

  20 = TEXT
  20.value = MyCustomName
  # you do not need "stdWrap" as pgampe mentioned, but it will work even with stdWrap
  20.stdWrap.typolink {
    # parameter was missing
    parameter.data = TSFE:id
    addQueryString = 1
    addQueryString.method = get
    additionalParams = &myCustomParameter=1
  }
}
```